# Hexbin in R: color scale in logarithmic base

Tags: r, graph, plot, scatter-plot

I'm making a scatter plot using the hexbin command in R, but I need to make the color scale in logarithmic base? For example, 1-10, then 10-100, 100-1000 after ... and so on ... anyone know how to do this in order to help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I disagree with calling this question "unclear" and closing it under that pretext. The question and the answer have been quite helpful in my work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is easy with ggplot2:

```
set.seed(42)
DF <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1e4),
                 y = rlnorm(1e4))

library(ggplot2)
library(hexbin)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = x, y= y)) +
  stat_binhex() +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "count", trans = "log", 
                      breaks = 10^(0:6))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Roland... But I would like the discrete scale, as it has in hexbin ... you know how to do a exponential discrete colors scale? :-)